# Help identifying a weird creature

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Okay, so there is this weird creature, which has been crawling around our house.
I can hear it moving around, and it's especially active in the dark. I've however been able to take a picture of it.
If it helps, it's a carnivore (I've thrown some hot dogs and such).
This weird thing is 25-30cm long, and the picture of it was taken from a balcony on the second floor. I've only been able to photograph it once, but never came close to it otherwise. We live in central Europe, in a small town that somehow resembles a village. As for the ecosystem, I don't quite know. Fields, rivers and forests are all in proximity of our house.

Thank you for your anwsers,

[image]

Comment: Can you please add more information? What is the approximate size? Where do you live (country, region, type of ecosystem, urban or rural, ...)? How close did you get? Did you take this picture from two meters away, from a window at the second floor, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black and white colours on the front and the grey back as well as the overall shape make me think it could be a [badger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badger). Given the location, it could be the [European badger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_badger) (*Meles meles*). The size matches, and badgers are omnivorous, so they can eat meat.

Answer (score 0):

It looks most like a hedgehog to me.  If you want to encourage a hedgehog, a bowl of fresh water is always important, and some cat food.  If you see a hedgehog in the day time, it is possibly in distress.